# Counting length of each words in c char

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have char* pointer and trying to count the length of each word. but I am not getting any result in debugger (just empty space). whatever I change , I dont get any result. the code :

```
void wordsLen(char* text, int* words, int n)
{
    int i, count = 0, s = 0;
    //words[countWords(text)]; // not important

    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != ' ')
        {
            count++;

        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%d",count);
        }
        printf("%d",count);//if I add this it types the count from 1 to the end
    }
}
```

I try to insert this array :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 100
void main()
{
    char t[] = "hello my name is.";
    int cum[N];
    wordsLen(t, cum, strlen(t));
    getch();
}
```

Since am not getting any result , I would like to know why , and is there any problem with the code for counting the length of words? like is it good for counting the length of word or do I need to change something.

Comment: Does `wordsLen` get a value?

Comment: Also, what is `words[countWords(text)];`?

Comment: C or C++ ? there are different languages

Comment: countwords(text) return the number of words in text* , and c++ , sorry for wrong.

Comment: So...  this compiles with no errors or warnings, yes?

Comment: little hint the `printf("%d", count)` is called twice in your `wordsLen`  function when the else branch is reached. Do you want this?

Comment: 'words[countWords(text)]; 'words' has no type.

Comment: yeah , I tried in the last printf (before closing the loop) and it basicly types the length of the sentence.

Comment: @MartinJames that's the parameter. Yes, that makes it even worse :>

Comment: You posted code that does not compile for multiple reasons, then started modifying it as people try to help.  I'm downvoting and vtc as 'unclear' :(

Comment: @Quentin oh...  didn't look there!  I guess I should not be surprised any more:(

Comment: The counting of the word length is not entire correct. because in the else you should set the `count` to `0` again. because otherwise you count the length of all words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little modification of your function.

```
void wordsLen(char* text, int* words, int n)
{
    int i, count = 0, s = 0;

    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%d",count);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
```

}

Comment: this is not correct because the last word is not counted i think.

Comment: @kevin Wallis I have added a print satement after the loop finishes which will print the counting of last word.

Answer (score 0):

Here some code for counting the words and there length:

```
void addWord(int* numberOfWords, int* count) {
    *numberOfWords = *numberOfWords + 1;
    *count = 0;
}

void print(int numberOfWords, int count) {
    printf("number of words %d \n", numberOfWords);
    printf("word length %d \n", count);
}

void wordsLen(char* text, int* words, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    //words[countWords(text)]; // dynamicly set the length

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char ch = text[i];
        if (ch != ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count > 0 && (ch == ' ' || (i == n - 1)))
        {
            print(numberOfWords + 1, count);
            addWord(&numberOfWords, &count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void wordsLen(char* text, int* words, int n) 
{ 
    int i, count = 0, s = 0; 
    //words[countWords(text)]; // not important 

    for (i=0; i <= n; i++) 
    { 
        if (text[i] != ' ' && text[i] != '\0') 
        {
            count++; 
        }
        else 
        { 
            printf("%d ",count);  
            count = 0;            
        }
        //printf("%d",count);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll not print the count of last word.

Comment: Please note <= in if condition